# Can this image be fixed? and why has this happened?

Tags: data-corruption

When I took this photo it was fine. I looked at it a few times on the camera on my way back home and it was fine. But when I got home and looked at it on the camera again, it was fine for a second but then went like this. It seems to be fine when viewed in files as medium size, but any larger and this happens.

The camera is a Canon IXUS 185

[image]

Comment: Have you transferred the images to a computer and opened the actual image files to see what they show?

Comment: I have put the memory card into a computer and they are the same another one of the pictures I took tonight has just done the same while on the computer

Comment: This one actually has a viable solution in one of the answers: [Corrupted JPG has undesired color bars overlay](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/73520/15871)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question appears to be a dupe, so I voted to close.

That being said - you need to determine if the file itself is really screwed up. Attempt to transfer it from camera to computer again. If you used a card reader, use a different card reader or connect the camera to the computer and try the transfer.

If, using different readers doesn't help, you could probably try using a recovery software on the card to see if you can get anything.

Unfortunately, it's not really possible to tell that a memory card is on it's way out until it starts messing up images.

It's time to retire that card and get a new one...or two...